# My nextcord (python) is ignoring the if statements below the first if statement and can't figure out why

Tags: python, nextcord

Sorry if this is a dumb question, however whenever I'm running my code it does not listen to the if statements within the if statement?

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Moderator')
async def activity(ctx):
    days = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    print(days)
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        for role in member.roles:
            if role.name == "Trusted Member":
                if role.name == "Exempt":
                    print("<@" + str(member.id) + "> has a perm exemption")
                elif role.name == "Temp Exempt":
                    print("<@" + str(member.id) + "> has a temp exemption, it has now been removed...")
                else:
                    counter = 0
                    channel = bot.get_channel(1)
                    async for message in channel.history(limit=None, after=days):
                        if message.author == member:
                            counter += 1
                    print("<@" + str(member.id) + "> has sent " + str(counter))
```

The script will not check if they have an exempt role and instead just proceed to check how many messages they have sent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont get what you're expecting to happen. How can the same variable be *equal* both "trusted member" and "exampt"?

Comment: the role variable contains all the member roles (discord) for example;
Exempt
Trusted Members
Honourable Members

So I want it to be able to firstly check to see if the member has the trusted member role, then make sure they dont have the exempt role and if they dont then count their messages.

Comment: Is it a list of values? You cant use ==. Use in. https://appdividend.com/2020/01/21/python-list-contains-how-to-check-if-item-exists-in-list/

Comment: thanks rani what i did was for each role.name i added it to a list and then used the in statement 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution I found with help thanks to Rani

````
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Moderator')
async def activity(ctx):
    days = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        role_names = []
        for role in member.roles:
            role_names.append(role.name)
        if "Trusted Member" in role_names:
            if "Exempt" in role_names:
                print("<@" + str(member.id) + "> has a perm exemption")
            elif "Temp Exempt" in role_names:
                print("<@" + str(member.id) + "> has a temp exemption, it has now been removed...")
            else:
                counter = 0
                channel = bot.get_channel(1)
                async for message in channel.history(limit=None, after=days):
                    if message.author == member:
                        counter += 1
                print("<@" + str(member.id) + "> has sent " + str(counter))```
````

Comment: If you think this code solves your problem, please mark it as answer

Comment: i cant i have to wait 2 days